# Importing model from Maya into Unity put's everything at position 0

Tags: python, unity-game-engine, maya

I am importing a model made in Maya using python scripting into Unity3D. I imported it simply by dragging the file into the assets folder in Unity. The problem however is that while the model looks correct, it's just the whole model that has a position, the actual position of each segment of the model is set to 0, 0, 0. It's only the visual mesh that is moved to where it should be, and this makes it a pain to interact with. Is there some way I can import the model to fix this or otherwise something I can do in Maya?

Comment: Sounds like either already in Maya or in some exporter/importer script the pivot point is incorrect ... Pretty hard for us to tell

Comment: I am using someone else's code so don't know much my self, but I will try having a look at the Maya code. But it should be able for the segments and not only the whole object to have correct position?